# jQuery load not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, get

I've only recently started using jQuery and am having no problems with most of it.  I've just started to look at using Ajax calls and have immediately hit a stumbling block.  To illustrate my problem I have written a small piece of demo code...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $.get("http://www.google.co.uk", function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }, "html");
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            #page
            {
                border:1px solid black;
                width:640px;
                height:480px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the page loads and then it's supposed to load the contents of a URL (google in this case) into the only div on the page, but it doesn't work.

Using the developer tools in Chrome I can see the request being sent, but it's marked as "canceled" (yes, with 1 l!)

I'd really appreciate someone helping me with what must be a really simple issue.  As I said, this is literally my 1st attempt at doing this.  It normally takes me a lot longer to get stuck!

Thanks in advance for any suggestions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd guess it's a security issue. You can't load pages from another server into your document. See http://api.jquery.com/load/ for more info.

Comment: Thanks @MassivePenguin.  I suspected something like that after having problems in the past with cross-domain issues.

Answer (score 2):

its because of [SAME ORIGIN POLICY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

alternate approach

make a server side proxy, have it request the page and send the response to your client side via json or your preferred format of choice

OR

[Using YQL as a proxy for cross-domain Ajax](http://ajaxian.com/archives/using-yql-as-a-proxy-for-cross-domain-ajax)

Comment: Thanks for the advice @3nigma.  It's not important to me so I won't need the above, but I'm sure since it's here that it'll help out some others.

Answer (score 1):

To load external link in ".load()"

create page say external.php

In external.php put following code:

```
<?php $url = 'http://ur/url/here'; echo $var = get_file_contents($url);?>
```

now load this page in jquery n it will load external link

$('div').load('external.php');

Comment: Thanks shefali - that's a simple solution.  I was using .Net for this and ended up writing a proxy to get whatever url I passed to it, so a similar solution.  It's funny seeing a question this old.  I can't believe now that I needed help with that! :D